# Show that $Lf:=f^{'''}$ is not a generator of a Feller-Dynkin Semi-Group

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces, stochastic-processes

Show that $Lf:=f^{'''}$ is not a generator of a Feller-Dynkin semigroup with domain $$D:=\{f \in C_{0}(\mathbb R):\;f^{'},\;f^{''},\;\;f^{'''}\in C_{0}(\mathbb R)\}.$$

I hence would like to either show that $L$ does not obey the positive maximum principle or there exists no $\lambda>0$ such that $\operatorname{range}(\lambda-L)=C_{0}(\mathbb R)$

I attempted to show the positive maximum principle does not hold by choosing $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ but I have seen that $f^{'''}(0)\leq 0$ and I cannot seem to find another example where the positive maximum principle may not hold.

Now, let $\lambda>0$ then then for any $f\in C_{0}(\mathbb R)$ we obtain: $(\lambda-L)f$ so I need to find an $f\in D$ such that $\lambda f-f^{'''}\notin C_{0}(\mathbb R)$, which seems like I am attempting to prove an incorrect statement.

I am stuck, has anyone got an idea how I can prove the initial statement?

We thus can prove this by showing that the above is not dissipative, i.e.

$$\exists \lambda > 0,\;\exists f \in D:\; \lvert\lvert\lambda f-Lf\rvert \rvert<\lambda\lvert \lvert f\rvert\rvert$$

Comment: It seems you're looking to obtain a contradiction to the Hille-Yosida theorem. Can you state explicitly which version of Hille-Yosida you are familiar with, in particular what the positive maximum principle looks like exactly?

Comment: I've updated the question above to include the fact that I want to show that the operator is not dissipative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g(x) = \cos(x) +0.1x$. Then $g$ has a local maximum at $x_0=\arcsin(0.1)=0.100167..$. Also,  $g'''(x) = \sin(x)$ is strictly positive at $x_0$. You won't have trouble producing a function $f\in D$, equal to $g$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, with a global maximum at $x_0$.  This $f$ shows that $L$ doesn't satisfy the maximum principle.